# App script for google sheet is executing but not triggering onUpdate

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, eventtrigger, onupdate

I have a Google sheet where form submissions are stored and I'm trying to run a Google App Script with an onUpdate trigger, to remove a generic chunk of text. I've run the script and got the "execution completed" message, but nothing happens after the script is run.
[App Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgWZ0.jpg)

```
function onUpdate() {
function replaceEverywhere () {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1Gm1B-IGifpPuRsVj5mFbIwx4T7g1VuTM0nlzDgHzzFo");
var = sheet SpreadsheetApp.SetActiveSheet(spreadsheets.getSheets()[0]);
var textFinder = sheet.createTextFinder("From: Leigh-on-Sea SS9, UK
Building No. Street & Postcode: ");
textFinder.replaceAllWith(" ");
}
}
```

There's a .json file for a trigger, but I don't know if they're linked??
[.json trigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkLLy.jpg)

Ideally, the end result would be to automatically remove the chunk of text from existing and new entries (in column J)... then I need new entries in column J to replace/update an existing Google calendar event location... is there an addon to update event location from sheet, on a trigger?

Comment: Please post actual code in question.- [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: What is a form submission?

Comment: Code added. Customer order form submission, from and external website

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
function replaceEverywhere() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1Gm1B-IGifpPuRsVj5mFbIwx4T7g1VuTM0nlzDgHzzFo");
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var textFinder = sheet.createTextFinder("From: Leigh-on-Sea SS9, UK Building No.Street & Postcode: ");
  textFinder.replaceAllWith(" ");
}


function onUpdate() {
  replaceEverywhere()
}
```

Comment: I still don't understad where the update trigger is coming from.  It kind of looks like a card service thing to me.

Comment: That has returned the error "Attempted to execute onUpdate, but could not save."

Comment: Isn't the onUpdate supposed to be the trigger? When the sheet is updated, I guess when the sheet is changed or added to? That's what I need

Comment: I have no knowledge of an upDateTrigger whatsoever. Triggers I know about: - [triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

Comment: This is exactly what I need, what part of the string do I need to alter to remove everything BEFORE "Postcode: " function removeTags(){
  var column = 14
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var data = sh.getRange(1,column,sh.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
  for(var n in data){
    if(data[n][0]==''){continue};// if cell empty then continue
    var str = data[n][0].toString();
    data[n][0]= str.substring(0,str.indexOf("Postcode: "));//remove everything after "tag"
  }
  sh.getRange(14,column,sh.getLastRow(),1).setValues(data);// update sheet with new data
}